# How deserialize json object array as array of json strings?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Consider json input:

```
{
    companies: [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1"
        }
    ],
    nextPage: 2
}
```

How deserialize this into class:

```
public class MyClass {
    List<String> companies;
    Integer nextPage;
}
```

Where `List<String> companies;` consists of strings:

```
{"id": 1,"name": "name1"}
{"id": 1,"name": "name1"}
```

`@JsonRawValue` doesn't work for `List<String> companies;`

Is there a way to configure [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) serialization to keep companies array with raw json string with annotations only? (E.g. without writing custom deserializator)

Comment: Have you fixed this problem? Did my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

There is no annotation-only solution for your problem. Somehow you have to convert `JSON Object` to `java.lang.String` and you need to specify that conversion.

You can:

1. Write custom deserializer which is probably most obvious solution but forbidden in question.
2. Register custom `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler` and handle `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException` situation in more sophisticated way.
3. Implement `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.Converter` interface and convert `JsonNode` to `String`. It is semi-annotational way to solve a problem but we do not implement the worst part - deserialisation.

Let's go to point 2. right away.

### 2. DeserializationProblemHandler

Solution is pretty simple:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
    @Override
    public Object handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext ctxt, JavaType targetType, JsonToken t, JsonParser p, String failureMsg) throws IOException {
        if (targetType.getRawClass() == String.class) {
            // read as tree and convert to String
            return p.readValueAsTree().toString();
        }
        return super.handleUnexpectedToken(ctxt, targetType, t, p, failureMsg);
    }
});
```

Read a whole piece of `JSON` as `TreeNode` and convert it to `String` using `toString` method. Helpfully, `toString` generates valid `JSON`. Downside, this solution has a global scope for given `ObjectMapper` instance.

### 3. Custom Converter

This solution requires to implement `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.Converter` interface which converts `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode` to `String`:

```
class JsonNode2StringConverter implements Converter<JsonNode, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(JsonNode value) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType getInputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return typeFactory.constructType(new TypeReference<JsonNode>() {
        });
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType getOutputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
        return typeFactory.constructType(new TypeReference<String>() {
        });
    }
}
```

and now, you can use annotation like below:

```
@JsonDeserialize(contentConverter = JsonNode2StringConverter.class)
private List<String> companies;
```

Solutions 2. and 3. solve this problem almost in the same way - read node and convert it back to `JSON`, but uses different approaches.

If, you want to avoid deserialising and serialising process you can take a look on solution provided in this article: [Deserializing JSON property as String with Jackson](https://cassiomolin.com/2017/01/24/deserializing-json-property-as-string-with-jackson/) and take a look at:

- [How to serialize JSON with array field to object with String field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824920/how-to-serialize-json-with-array-field-to-object-with-string-field)
- [How to get a part of JSON as a plain text using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999355/how-to-get-a-part-of-json-as-a-plain-text-using-jackson)
- [How to extract part of the *original* text from JSON with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864072/how-to-extract-part-of-the-original-text-from-json-with-jackson)