# Extract the inner JSON object as String in Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I would like to deserialize the following JSON object using Jackson.

```
[
    {
      "_foo": "foo-value",
      "_bar": {// bar json object }
    },
    {
      "_foo": "foo-value",
      "_bar": {// bar json object }
    }
]
```

I don't care about the `bar` JSON object so I just want to parse it as String. Here is how my Pojo class looks like:

```
@Data
public class Document {

  @JsonProperty("_foo")
  private String foo;

  @JsonProperty("_bar")
  private String bar;
}
```

When I try to deserialize the object using Jackson with the following code. It throws an exception.

```
List<Document> docs = mapper.readValue(fileContent, new TypeReference<List<Document>>() {
        })
```

Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
```

What part am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at my answer to [How deserialize json object array as array of json strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077279/how-deserialize-json-object-array-as-array-of-json-strings/61110073#61110073) question. You have to use `@JsonDeserialize(converter = JsonNode2StringConverter.class)` annotation over `bar` property and it should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care then you can ignore this property:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"_bar"})
public static class Document { ...
```

or you can add setter with JsonNode:

```
    @JsonProperty("_bar")
    private String bar;

    @JsonSetter
    private void setBar(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        this.bar = jsonNode.toString();
    }

    private void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
```

or use JsonNode as field instead:

```
    @JsonProperty("_bar")
    private JsonNode bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is at `"_bar": {// bar json object }`

jackson considers it as `JSON_OBJECT`, not a `String`.

You can create a class for Bar and use as,

```
@JsonProperty("_bar")
private Bar bar;
```

You can also try with JSONNode,

```
@JsonProperty("_bar")
private JsonNode bar;
```

Comment: Thanks, now when I try to treat it as a String it gives me:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input