# Read the outer-most JSON object but not the inner ones using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61341049/extract-the-inner-json-object-as-string-in-jackson) question but it's a little different.

Let's say I have a json document defined like this:

```json
[
    { "type" : "Type1", 
      "key1" : "value1" },
    { "type" : "Type2", 
      "key2" : "value2" }
]
```

I want to read this json document into a list of strings (`List<String>`). I only want to read the outer-most list into the Java `List`, the json objects inside the list should be left as-is inside the list. The result should be equivalent to this (I ignore newlines etc):

```
var myList = List.of("{\"type\": \"Type1\", \"key1\": \"value1\"}, {\"type\": \"Type2\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}")
```

Note that I *don't* want to create any DTO to hold some intermediate representation. I just want everything below the "list" to be represented "as-is".

How can I achieve this?

I'm using Jackson 2.12.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to hold intermediate representation in a DTO, then one way in which the required deserialization can be achieved is:

```
// Create a ObjectMapper (of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// Read the json string into a List. This will be deserialized as a collection of LinkedhashMap
 List<LinkedHashMap> list = mapper.readValue(getInputString(), List.class);
//Iterate over the deserialized collection and create a JSONObject from every LinkedHashMap
 List<String> result = list.stream()
                           .map(map -> new JSONObject(map).toString())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will produce:

```
[{"key1":"value1","type":"Type1"}, {"key2":"value2","type":"Type2"}]
```

Downside of this approach is, it takes a hit on performance.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this be quite bad from a performance perspective? It will both convert it into a "Map", then into a "JsonObject" that is then converted back into a (json) String. I figure that something like this could be made _faster_ since there would be less data to parse (just the outer list).

Comment: Yes, that is the downside of this approach. This can be avoided if a DTO is in place, through which specific fields which are not required to be deserialized, can be avoided by `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotations