# Deserialise an array of JSON objects to a list of strings

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a scenario where I need to deserialise a `JSON` array to a list of strings.

My class is:

```
public class Pojo {  
  private String message;  
  private ArrayList<String> details;  
}
```

`JSON` payload:

```
{
"message":"some value",
"details":[]    
}
```

If I try to deserialise the below `JSON`, it works:

```
{
"message":"working example",
"details": [ 
"First element of the array", 
"Second element"
]
}
```

In this case:

```
details = ["First element of the array", "Second element"]
```

If the array contains `JSON` objects as elements it will fail with `MismatchedInputException`:

```
{
  "message":"working example",
  "details":[ 
    {"First":"Value"}, 
    "Second element"
]}
```

For the second example, I'm expecting

```
details = ["{\"First\":\"Value\"}", "Second element"]
```

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: What does the java class definition look like for the case with json objects? Your question just has details as ArrayList<String>. Oh I guess you are trying to make a list of strings that contain escaped json.

Comment: Take a look at: [How deserialize json object array as array of json strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077279/how-deserialize-json-object-array-as-array-of-json-strings/61110073#61110073)

Comment: Thanks @MichałZiober! I solved it by implementing a custom deserializer.